# Under ddos attack, legit packets increase length also?

Tags: linux, ddos, udp, packets

I would like to know about packets length, for example, with normal traffic (without DDoS attack) packets length is 20-40, which I believe is normal, once DDoS attack starts packets length goes over 1000. I would like to know if these 1000 length packets are only bad ones or normal ones might increase their length also because of the DDoS attack?

Answer (score 0):

An ongoing DDOS-attack can't affect legitimate traffic - how would the senders of the legitimate traffic know?

But 20-40 bytes sounds very low for packet size. Do you have a very specific usecase? Normal traffic has much larger packets.

And DDOS attacks also comes in variants with small packets.